# G++ math.h problem

Tags: math, include, g++

I'm hoping someone has come across this problem before too.

I am trying to use visual studio to develop for Linux with G++.

I am trying to include math.h and use tanf()

If I compile with the g++ compiler, "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++", everything works

but if I add this include directory, which the docs say is the right one, and
"CodeSourcery\Sourcery G++ Lite\arm-none-linux-gnueabi\libc\usr\include\"
then include math.h,

visual studio does not recognize any of the math functions, namely tanf().

anyone have any idea why?

thanks for any help.

edit:
the same app successfully compiles with this command line:
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -o test main.cpp "-I%PALMPDK%\include" "-I%PALMPDK%\include\SDL" "-L%PALMPDK%\device\lib" -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined -lSDL -lGLESv2 -lpdl

Comment: "I am trying to use visual studio to develop for Linux with G++."  this statement fills me with fear and rage.

Comment: I don't know why, but I also don't know why you just install linux. Even if you don't want to do a full true install, you can still use a virtual machine. Linux is great.

Comment: It's ok, we were all noobs once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution!

I downloaded and installed MinGW instead, and that works fine. I have all the function prototypes for extra stuff like gettimeofday(), and all the regular suff like tanf() is still working fine.

ps: visual studio even has a button for "Use Output Window" where it nicely dumps any errors that are generated by "arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++"

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use visual studio to develop for Linux with G++.

Don't.

It looks like you are trying to use a cross compiler to build for an embedded ARM machine. Likely, you won't be able to get away with just the compiler - you'll need a whole root environment in order to link to anything more than libc. Visual Studio, while a good IDE, really can't be molded into this role. You will really need an actual Linux machine, with your corresponding root environment (be it home grown, buildroot, openembedded, etc).

Comment: sorry, but you seem to have misunderstood my question. I have added a custom build tool to visual studio, and the project builds fine...but when I include the gcc libraries so I can use the intellisense for non-c++ functions, the math functions start to bug out.

Answer (score 1):

1) In C++, you include `<cmath>`, not `math.h`.

2) in C++, you use `tan` with float arguments (there is an overload), not `tanf`.

Comment: `math.h` is still valid in C++ (although `cmath` is preferred), and it still offers `tanf`.

Comment: @peoro: That is undefined behaviour, vendor specific.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that Visual Studio sees `<math.h>`, and thinks that must refer to the Microsoft math header (which is fundamentally antediluvian and lacks support for C99 niceties such as `tanf`).  This is just guessing though, since you haven't posted the actual error that you're encountering; what exactly do you mean when you say "visual studio does not recognize any of the math functions"?  Does it fail to compile?  To link?  What is the exact text of the error message?  What are the exact options that are being passed to the compiler or linker?

Comment: when I include math.h, and then right-click/open document <math.h>,
the header does say "This file is part of the GNU C Library."
so it is the right file. Also, In one of the sub-header files, features.h, It says this define:
_ISOC99_SOURCE -> Extensions to ISO C89 from ISO C99.
activates this section of math.h:
#if defined __USE_ISOC99
/* Include the file of declarations again, this time using `float'
   instead of `double' and appending f to each function name.  */

but still, while this will compile with the g++ compiler, visual studio still says that the identifier tanf() is undefined

Comment: @Nick: You still haven't told us what the actual command that is used to invoke the compiler is.  What exactly does MSVC pass to the compiler?  What exactly do you pass to the compiler when you build successfully?